# Is RelativeLayout better than LinearLayout for my scenario?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to get something like this on my screen.

[image]

On the left there is an icon and a label and on the right there is a icon and a label.

Currently I am doing this by a `LinearLayout` but I'm not sure how this will behave on big displays as I am hardcoding the distance between the two things. In `RelativeLayout` I could use `alignParentLeft` and `alignParentRight`. However, I can't seem to get the TextView aligned in the center as my `LinearLayout` does.

Here is the `LinearLayout` I use:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/myimg1"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="4 comments"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="160dp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/myimg"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="3 handlers"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: use `gravity="center_vertical"` in your linearlayout, or `layout_gravity="center_vertical"` in the textview

Comment: add layout_gravity="center" to your LinearLayout and all of the elements will get center aligned

Comment: or, use `layout_height="match_parent"` and `gravity="center_vertical"` in the textview

Comment: I generally go with RelativeLayout unless I need to specify weights for my Views.  There's no other reason to use LinearLayout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example that might work:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
  android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
  android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
  android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/leftIcon"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_search" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/centerText"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/leftIcon"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageRight"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textSize="14dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="4 comments"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageRight"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textRight"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_search" />

  <TextView
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:id="@+id/textRight"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textSize="14dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="3 handlers"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="25dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

(I replaced the images with something in my project)

Here's the preview I got:

[image]

Comment: Looks like you might want the main textview to have a diffferent "gravity". I put it centered because I wasn't 100% sure what your requirements were.

Comment: I want the `4 comments` TextView to be next to the image just like you've done it on the right hand side.

Comment: The problem I have is that I want the TextView to be aligned well next to the Image....such that it is in the center of the image's height. right now it starts at the bottom of the image height.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, RelativeLayouts can be more performant than LinearLayout (especially if there are a lot of other nested layouts required in the Linear setup).

If you have a complicated layout, that will require you to nest a bunch of layouts together, it is time to think about alternatives (like Relative).

To set your TextView to align center have you tried: alignParentCenter?

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html#CENTER_IN_PARENT

Comment: unless I am missing something I don't see `alignParenceCenter` for TextView

Answer (score 0):

if you want them to center , then do a relative layout. Pin the 2nd image in center and add other in relative position.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ff00ff"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"    
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="4 comments"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"   
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#00ff00" 
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="3 handlers"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```